# Is it legal to post links to publications found on google scholar?

Tags: support, scope, policy

I have just started my Ms.c, and I'm now really starting to read publications, and I think that many times the link to a paper could make it easier to formulate and scope a question.

I guess that some publications are publicly available, while others may be only in a journal, and readers have to buy it. I have also seen links from google scholar to my universities library, which probably paid for having that article\a copy of the journal. So: How do I determine if its legal to publish a link to a publication\paper?

I will consider all answers as **IANAL** answers

Answer (score 1):

**IANAL**

I doubt very much that posting a google scholar link will cause any problems. Such links are public. If the person clicking the link doesn't have access, I think the link won't actually work. You might want to spend a few minutes seeing if an author page has a link that can be accessed by anyone.

And again, **IANAL**

Comment: My question was actually about posting a link that I found using google scholar, but direction to a PDF. And thanks for the IANAL - haven't though that this may scare people.